# Rubyのプロセス間通信で複数の情報をやり取りしたい

Tags: ruby

IO.pipeを使って、
子プロセスの値を親プロセスに渡すことができたのですが、
子プロセスから複数の値を親プロセスに渡したい場合は
どのようにしたらよいのでしょうか？

```
require 'thread'
require 'open3'
require 'time'
require 'find'

# プロセス間通信用
read, write = IO.pipe
# プロセス処理
pid = Process.fork do
  # 子プロセスで読み出さないのでクローズ
  read.close
  # 外部コマンド実施
  stdin, stdout, stderr, stdth = Open3.popen3(コマンド)
  # 外部コマンドの終了待ち
  commth.join
  # 外部コマンド結果を書込み
  write.puts stdout.read
  write.close
end

# プロセス処理終了待ち
Process.waitpid pid

# 書き込まないのでクローズ
write.close
# 子プロセスで書き込んだ値を取得
result = read.gets
read.close
puts "it takes #{result}"

puts "end"
```

Comment: `result = read.gets` となっていますが、これだと子プロセスからの入力を一行しか読み取りません。「複数の値を親プロセスに渡したい」というのは、子プロセスからの入力を全て取得したい、という意味なのでしょうか？

Comment: 質問が明確でなく申し訳ありません。意図としては子プロセスから「stdout.read」の値だけでなく、複数の、たとえば「stderr.read」の値も返したい場合になります

Comment: そうですね、pipe をもう一本作成するのはどうでしょうか。例えば `r2, w2 = IO.pipe` として、`w2.puts stderr.read` などとするなどです(close 処理や読み出し処理も適宜追加します)。

Comment: ありがとうございます。pipe を増やすという発想は全くでできてませんでした！早速ためしてみます！ありがとうございます。